# Between operator not working properly in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

ERROR: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
"FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

```
 SELECT
    
        SUM("ASSET")
    
    FROM  component WHERE "Extraction Date" = '20201231' AND  "Account Start Date"
    
         BETWEEN '20151221' AND ADD_MONTHS(to_date('20151221', 'YYYYMMDD'),3) ;
```

Comment: Add `ADD_MONTHS(to_date('20151221', 'YYYYMMDD'),3) ` to the select list, and remove the between, and see what happens.

Comment: Use appropriate data types. String types aren't appropriate for date/times. Use a date/time type. And you may also consider using a half open interval with `>=` and `<` instead of  `BETWEEN` to prevent surprises when precision of the timestamps gets increased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *mixing* strings and dates; that won't work. I presume that those "date" columns are, actually, strings - at least, that's how you treat them.

This: `ADD_MONTHS(to_date('20151221', 'YYYYMMDD'),3)` returns a **date** value, so you'll have to convert it to a string with appropriate format mask. Therefore:

```
select sum ("ASSET")
  from component
 where     "Extraction Date" = '20201231'
       and "Account Start Date" 
           between '20151221'
               and to_char (add_months (to_date ('20151221', 'YYYYMMDD'), 3), 'yyyymmdd');
```

---

If those columns are dates, then *everything* should be a date:

```
select sum ("ASSET")
  from component
 where     "Extraction Date" =  date '2020-12-31'
       and "Account Start Date" 
           between date '2015-12-12' and add_months(date '2015-12-21', 3);
```

---

Also, note that we, working with Oracle, don't particularly like column names enclosed into double quotes, having spaces within. You, obviously, can have such a column names, but that's just too painful (from my point of view). You have to match letter case every time you work with them. So, I'd suggest (for the future)

```
select sum (asset)
  from component
 where     extraction_date =  date '2020-12-31'
       and account_start_date
           between date '2015-12-12' and add_months(date '2015-12-21', 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
SELECT
    
        SUM("ASSET")
    
    FROM  component WHERE "Extraction Date" = to_date('20201231', 'YYYYMMDD') AND  "Account Start Date"
    
         BETWEEN to_date('20151221', 'YYYYMMDD') AND ADD_MONTHS(to_date('20151221', 'YYYYMMDD'),3) ;
```

If this solution doesn't work, add the desc of table.